# Set parents state from unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends Component {

   constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            usuarios:[], 
            hayUsuarios: false
        };
    }

    render() {

        var usuarios = [];

        usuarios = this.state.usuarios.map(function(u){
            return <Usuario key={u.cId} id={u.cId} nombre={u.dNombre} pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios()} />
        });


        return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
            <AdicionarUsuario pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios()}/>
            {usuarios}
        </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.pedirUsuarios();
    }

    pedirUsuarios = () =>{
        fetch("https://shielded-escarpment-86252.herokuapp.com/usuarios.json")
        .then( resp => resp.json() )
        .then(json => this.setState({usuarios: json}))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

AdicionarUsuario

```
class AdicionarUsuario extends Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {nombre:""};
}

onChange = (event)  =>{
    this.setState({nombre: event.target.value});
}

adicionarUsuario = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.nombre);
    this.enviarPost(this.state.nombre);
}

enviarPost = (nomb) =>{

    let datos = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({nombre: nomb}),
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    fetch("https://shielded-escarpment-86252.herokuapp.com/adicionarUsuario", datos)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(algo => this.actualizar(algo))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

actualizar = (json) =>{
    console.log(json);
    if(json.respuesta){
        this.props.pedirUsuarios();
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.adicionarUsuario}>
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.nombre} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Post"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar"/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

}

Usuario

```
class Usuario extends Component{

constructor(){
    super();
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.nombre}</h3>
            <SubirCancion id={this.props.id} />
            <ActualizarUsuario id={this.props.id} />
            <EliminarUsuario id={this.props.id} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I'm getting: 
"Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op."

**EDIT1**: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pedirUsuarios' of undefined,
deleting the brackets didn't solve the issue.

**EDIT2**: Added AdicionarUsuario and Usuario components

**EDIT3**: Here's the jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/JuanDavid31/69z2wepo/88446/

And i need to re-render App component when child component asks for i, the problem is that child components are not going to be rendred when ajax is done. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the code for `AdicionarUsuario `?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the app is supposed to do, since it's in spanish, but here's the new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/smlacerda5/69z2wepo/88474/  
I had to remove one of the components because it was provided, something about Cancionar??? Everything looked good, except you had some function(){ // 'this' keyword is window in here } and you needed () => { // 'this' keyword is the component in here }

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually stuck in a loop. Not a very great error message, but what's happening is that you're calling this.pedirUsuarios() in your component, which then sets state, which then rerenders, which calls this.pedirUsuarios again, which then rerenders, and so on. I can't tell if you're trying to pass the function pedirUsuarios down as a prop, or pass the usuarios down down. If you want to pass the function down, do as below. If you want to pass the data down, then just change out this.pedirUsuarios in the render to this.state.usuarios.

```
render() {

    var usuarios = [];

    usuarios = this.state.usuarios.map(function(u){
        return <Usuario key={u.cId} id={u.cId} nombre={u.dNombre} pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios} />
    });


    return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <AdicionarUsuario pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios}/>
        {usuarios}
    </div>
    );
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.pedirUsuarios();
}

pedirUsuarios = () =>{
    fetch("https://shielded-escarpment-86252.herokuapp.com/usuarios.json")
    .then( resp => resp.json() )
    .then(json => this.setState({usuarios: json}))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say that this is not working, still the same

Comment: Check your child components then. Add a jsfiddle if you can and I’ll take a look.

Comment: Added the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<AdicionarUsuario pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios()}/>
```

to

```
<AdicionarUsuario pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios}/>
```

The extra `()` in your call is causing the repeated renders and the error.

**EDIT1**: You also need to make the same change here

```
<Usuario key={u.cId} id={u.cId} nombre={u.dNombre} pedirUsuarios={this.pedirUsuarios()} />
```